# PHP preg_match_all() return dynamic string in the regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I am using `PHP` and regular expressions to find:

```
preg_match_all('/\{\{include:[a-zA-Z0-9_]{25}\}\}/i', $content, $include_matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

According to the PHP documentation, `$include_matches` should give me the original string, and the results inside of the parenthesis (PREG_PATTERN_ORDER flag), exactly what I want. The problem is that the result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {{include:rec_ih6tk504c23dfdf4a3qqK}}
        )
 )
```

I want the result to be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => rec_ih6tk504c23dfdf4a3qqK
        )
 )
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: From your question; *"...and the results inside of the parenthesis..."*. You have no parentheses in your expression

Comment: i'm sure it was translation fail ;)
braces, brackets, parantheses... here in germany it's all the same word with an adjective before ;)

Answer (score 4):

just use:

```
preg_match_all('/\{\{include:([a-zA-Z0-9_]{25})\}\}/', $content, $include_matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$include_matches= $include_matches[1];
```

you have to insert a capture-group